# Proving a Particular Coefficient of a Power Series Equals $0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, proof-writing

Suppose I have a particular function

$$F(x,z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty{A_n(x)\frac{z^n}{n!}}$$

and suppose, through the use of a particular computer algebra system, that the particular polynomial coefficients of the form $A_{qn+r}(x)$ equals $0$.  For example if $q=6,r=1$, then the sequence of polynomial coefficients is

$$\{A_0(x), 0, A_2(x), A_3(x), A_4(x), A_5(x), A_6(x), 0, A_8(x),...\}$$
how could I show by proof that this happens for all coefficients of the form $A_{qn+r}(x)$  I'm sure that the particular function would be helpful to know, but I'm more interested in the particular strategy.

As an example, to prove the odd $Bernoulli$ numbers are all $0$, you can just show that, after moving the linear term, the left hand side is an even function.  So

$$f(x)=\frac{x}{e^x-1}+\frac{x}{2}=f(-x)$$

with proof of this [here](http://planetmath.org/theoddbernoullinumbersarezero).  The problem here is that I don't get this luxury since the power series is way past being an even or odd function.  One of the things i do know though is that, as a polynomial, the coefficient equals $0$, so if I know the form of the polynomial, I could try to solve.  However, this becomes increasingly difficult as the powers become quickly large, so this would not be an approach, I think, to tackle this problem.

What would be a method in order to determine whether or not this would be true?   I tried to tag "proof strategy", but did not see the tag below anymore, so I'm not sure what other tag would be appropriate here.

Comment: There's a generalization of the odd/even method called _multisectioning_ that might be applicable here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_multisection - unfortunately, if your $q$ is larger than about 4 or so then things may get inordinately complicated. I would be more inclined towards a combinatorial approach, determining what your $A_n(x)$ is counting and showing through an argument there that it has to be zero (but I'm guessing that you're working the other way on a problem much like that!).

Comment: Interesting...so, i think then, I can subtract out the multisection from the original power series and show that there is no change in the coefficient values.  I am at work currently so I'll have to test this method later, but that seems pretty legitimate...